# Set the focus to a HTML Textbox or Button in a WebBroswer control

Tags: vb.net, tabs, webbrowser-control, setfocus

I am opening a website in a `WebBrowser` control using VB.NET 2008. On the fourth page of the website, I want to focus the control by triggering the tab key programmatically. I am using the following code:

```
If adtxt.Text = "http://aojsl.com/dfassfeed2.php" Then
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
End If
```

However, my code is unable to trigger the tab key. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: What does "my code is unable" mean? Do you get an error message? What exactly happens? What does it do when you use the debugger with a break point on the `If adtxt.Text` line?

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: Dont use the TAB key, I'll find you a more reliable method to set the focus to a HTLM element in the WebBrowser control

Comment: actually  there is a button on the 4th page of the website  i want to bring the focus control on that button So i am using this code

Comment: Did you need any further clarification? If you want to use the Tabs I can help you, you just use the second method and then the WebBrowser control will have focus.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson ..... Is th e method 2 is in c# coding???

Comment: No I converted it into VB.Net using http://CodeChanger.com, I got the code from the Microsoft thread, doesn't the code work?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.google.com/"
    Do
     Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop While webBrowser1.IsBusy = True
End Sub 

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("q").focus 'Set focus to the search text field
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("btnI").focus 'Set focus to the google "I Am feeling lucky button"
End Sub
```

Method 2

I converted it to VB.Net from this [MSDN thread: Focus issues with System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1b50fec6-6596-4c0a-9191-32cd059f18f7)

You will need to change the ActiveElement in `webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement.Focus()` to the textbox or button.

```
Public Partial Class Form1
    Inherits Form
  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim host As New WindowsFormsHost()
    im webBrowser As New WebBrowser()
    host.Child = webBrowser
    elementHost1.Child = host

    webBrowser.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))
    Me.Activated += Function() Do
      Console.WriteLine(Me.ActiveControl)
      If webBrowser.Document <> Nothing Then
        If Me.ActiveControl = elementHost1 AndAlso webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement <> Nothing Then
          webBrowser.Document.ActiveElement.Focus()
        End If
      End If
    End Function
  End Sub
End Class
```

Method 3

Another way might be to do it in the HTML, eg:

```
OnLoad="document.myform2.mybutton.focus();">
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say that the html of youre page is:

```
<button id="btn">Ok</button><input id="txt">
```

you can set focus in this way:

```
If adtxt.Text = "http://aojsl.com/dfassfeed2.php" Then
    webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("btn").focus()
    webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("txt").focus()
End If
```

Comment: but my program is unable to get id

Answer (score 0):

Another way:
use the `GetElementsByTagName(TagName)`

lets say that your html is:

```
<button>no</button>
<button>no</button>
<button onclick='alert(1);'>--focus me!--</button>
<button>no</button>
```

```
   Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection
        Dim WebOC As WebBrowser = WebBrowser1
        Elems = WebOC.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In Elems
            If elem.InnerHtml = "--focus me!--" Then
                elem.Focus()
                elem.InvokeMember("click")

            End If

        Next
```

another one:

```
Dim num As Integer = 1
        Dim elms As HtmlElementCollection
        Dim wb As WebBrowser = WebBrowser1
        elms = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In elms
            If elem.Id = "" Then
                elem.Id = "button" & num.ToString
                num = num + 1
            End If
        Next

        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button3").Focus()
```

Comment: give me the html of your page and i try to customize my code.

Comment: I think so that its solution is by triggering TAB key programatically. But i dont know the code for triggering the TAB key . So can u plz tell me how to trigger TAb key presses Automatically by program code??

Comment: How can i send u the HTML of page ?

Comment: Dont use the "SendKeys" , if you want that your program works call the html element. you can just sendkeys.send("{TAB}") but is not the solution.

Comment: Listen i am using "    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}") " but it is just focusing the control on first page of the website . But is not working on the 4th page of the website. Any opinion about this ????

Comment: On the first page  u have to login  on the second page u have to select an assignment  on the 3rd page u have to fill a form and on the 4th page u have to press a button named next

Comment: Send keys.Send("{TAb}") id working on the 1st page of the website . Y it is not working on the 4th page of the website

Comment: maybe your page is not fully loaded and then you can't call the elements. send me the html of the page to my email: ipxforum@gmail.com

Comment: ok i have sent the mail to u . check the mail and tell me either u have got the files???

Comment: i got this. check youre mail. :)

Answer (score 0):

To focus the select element by using the focus function in vb.net. For exsample,

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("password").Focus()
```

This will put the focus on the element called password!

Use `Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("YOURelement")` to find the correct element and then add `.Focus()` to focus on the one you want! :D

Answer (score -1):

Do this Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(textbox1.text).Focus()

make a Textbox and then if you want to Spambot it easy Detects everytime your Typ you Write and Send